Как менять веса и всё остальное в блоках LSTM/GRU в Keras?
Как менять веса и всё остальное в блоках LSTM/GRU в Keras?
Предположим, я хочу взять у каждого/у одного блока нейронной сети, посмотреть и изменить, или, например, добавить что-то своё. Например, я хочу взять эти веса(обведены зелёным цветом)


Возможно, ответы к этому вопросу вам будут полезны: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861460/how-to-interpret-weights-in-a-lstm-layer-in-keras
